# php + mysql + google map

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

i am using google map to create a dynamic google map that take locations(lat, lon) stored in the database using php mysql and display the selected locations by markers on the map 
  but the problem is that i get the map displayed with a blue color without anything else 
if anyone can help me i will appreciate that

## map.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("map") or die(mysql_error());
?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
            #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Sample code written by August Li
            var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
            }           
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poi_example")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $name = $row['name'];
  $lat = $row['lat'];
  $lon = $row['lon'];
  $desc = $row['desc'];



  echo("addmarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");

}

?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
     <div id="map"></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

## the database is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `poi_example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `lat` text NOT NULL,
  `lon` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `poi_example`
--

INSERT INTO `poi_example` (`id`, `name`, `desc`, `lat`, `lon`) VALUES
(1, '100 Club', 'Oxford Street, London  W1&lt;br/&gt;3 Nov 2010 : Buster Shuffle&lt;br/&gt;', '51.514980', '-0.144328'),
(2, '93 Feet East', '150 Brick Lane, London  E1 6RU&lt;br/&gt;7 Dec 2010 : Jenny &amp; Johnny&lt;br/&gt;', '51.521710', '-0.071737'),
(3, 'Adelphi Theatre', 'The Strand, London  WC2E 7NA&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Love Never Dies', '51.511010', '-0.120140'),
(4, 'Albany, The', '240 Gt. Portland Street, London  W1W 5QU', '51.521620', '-0.143394'),
(5, 'Aldwych Theatre', 'Aldwych, London  WC2B 4DF&lt;br/&gt;11 Oct 2010 : Dirty Dancing', '51.513170', '-0.117503'),
(6, 'Alexandra Palace', 'Wood Green, London  N22&lt;br/&gt;30 Oct 2010 : Lynx All-Nighter', '51.596490', '-0.109514');
```

Comment: If you zoom out you'll likely find yourself off the west coast of Africa.

Comment: ok now i can see the map but without any selected markers from the database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how it should be (sorry for the indentation):

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost:4040", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
            #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Sample code written by August Li
            var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
            }           
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poi_example")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $name = $row['name'];
  $lat = $row['lat'];
  $lon = $row['lon'];
  $desc = $row['desc'];



  echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>$name</b><br />$desc');\n");

}

?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
     <div id="map"></div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

The issue is: addmarker in the call va addMarker in function definition (JS is case-sensitive)

Comment: man now it do not display anything even the google map

Comment: sorry man i did not change the bd name  thanks a lot