# display google map with php and mysql using the longitude and latitude stored in the database is not workingg

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, inner-join

I have a map page that include a Google map  to display  users static  locations using the php and mysql  because the **longitude and lattitude** are stored in the database in **village table**  but the **village id** is in the a foreign key in the user table so I used the **INNER join** but the problem is that the browser do not show anything.

## map.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php print "$firstname $lastname"; ?></title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>

<style type="text/css">
            #map {
    width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 76px;
    left: 253px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9YBiNmZG9jIWY32FzJwn92iuJtJZHjfc&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
                       new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
            var center = null;
            var map = null;
            var currentPopup;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
                var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                bounds.extend(pt);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pt,
                    icon: icon,
                    map: map
                });
                var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: info,
                    maxWidth: 300
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    if (currentPopup != null) {
                        currentPopup.close();
                        currentPopup = null;
                    }
                    popup.open(map, marker);
                    currentPopup = popup;
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                    map.panTo(center);
                    currentPopup = null;
                });
            }           
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ZOOM_PAN
                    }
                });


<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT lattitude, longitude FROM user u 
                      INER JOIN village v
                       ON u.village = v.id")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
 // $name = $row['user_name'];
  $lat = $row['lattitude'];
  $lon = $row['longitude'];
  //$desc = $row['desc'];
//'<b>$name</b>


  echo("addMarker($lat, $lon <br />');\n");

}

?>
 center = bounds.getCenter();
     map.fitBounds(bounds);

     }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
<?php  /*require_once('header.php');*/ ?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
      <div id="page">
            <div id="wide-content">
              <div id="map"></div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php /*require_once('footer.php');*/ ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

## database stucture

village table:

- id
- village_name
- district_id
- lattitude
- longitude

user table:

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- governorate
- district
- village
- birth_date
- email_address
- specialization
- user_name
- password
- interest
- registered_date
- last_log_date

I think the problem is in the query of the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Your select query is very limiting. You have only selected two fields in the two tables and the two fields you are trying to join on have been left out of your selection. Try using select * from both the tables and rectify the typos and you will be good to go

Answer (score 0):

If i look at your query there is a typo:
SELECT lattitude, longiude FROM user u 
                      INER JOIN village v
                       ON u.village = v.id

This:
longiude => longitude

Comment: sorry  it was a mistake in writing here  but this is not the error  can you help me ??

Comment: Does the query give you the results you want? If you parse it in for instance PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: sir the browser do not show anything  even the google map does not appear

Comment: Weel you have this function:
echo("addMarker($lat, $lon <br />');\n");

Can you alter it to:
echo("addMarker($lat, $lon,'Info in the window');").PHP_EOL;

Notice the extra ',' in the function, as the javascript function as 3 parameters that it expects.
..
Question remains, if you run the query in for instance PHPMyadmin do you have results in the database? Thats a good place start if give it some extra error handling if the query fails.

Does it give a javascript error? Check the console in Google Chrome for that for instance..

Comment: Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633604/php-mysql-google-map?rq=1

If you tried anything i said? Then you must be really fast.. ;-)

Comment: sir the querry are correct and it select the needed and correct results  and now it show a border for the map that i added without the google map or any data in the google map